# Copy all content from a word table cell into the end of a word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I need to do data migration of thousands of word documents. The source documents contains tables with cell content (text, images, objects etc). The contents of tables with a specific header needs to be copied to the end of a specific word document. In most cases the content will be copied to a new file, but in some case tables that are related will have their contents copied to the same file, hence I need to know how paste to the end of the file as well.

I am writing a C# console program to do this. I need to now how to copy and paste all content (not just text) from a table into the end of a word document.

I can open the relevant documents and select the table cell, but I am stuck at copying all the content over. This is the main routine that will be doing the copying.

```
foreach (Table table in document.Tables)
{
    for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        var header = table.Cell(row, 1);
        var headerText = header.Range.Text;

        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            // if contains header, write to new file
            if (headerText.StartsWith(tableHeaders[j]))
            {
                // get new numbered file name
                string filename = getFilename(targetDir, file, j + 1);
                Console.WriteLine(filename);

                //Create a new document
                Document newDocument = application.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                // table cell to copy from: table.Cell(row + 1, 1)
                // document to copy into: newDocument
                // I am stuck here

                // save file
                newDocument.SaveAs2(filename);
                newDocument.Close();
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if (headerText.StartsWith(tableHeaders[j]))
{
    // get file name
    string filename = getFilename(targetDir, file, j + 1);

    //Create a new document
     Document newDocument = application.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    var copyFrom = table.Cell(row + 1, 1).Range;
    int start = newDocument.Content.End - 1;
    int end = newDocument.Content.End;
    var copyTo = newDocument.Range(start, end);

    copyFrom.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
    copyTo.FormattedText = copyFrom.FormattedText;

    // save file
    newDocument.SaveAs2(filename);
    newDocument.Close();
}
```